# Looping through a dynamic website url in python

Tags: python, loops, scrapy

I am writing a script that uses Python and Scrapy.The script itself is finished the only part that has brought up an issue is the URLs being used. The URL format is as shown below;
https://mygames.com/6552/4

The URL keeps changing after four minutes e.g current time is 17:28, at 17:32 the new URL will be; https://mygames.com/6552/5

The URL loops until the last digit reaches 38 which adds to the preceding last number .e,g the new URL after 38 rounds is going to be;
https://mygames.com/6553/0.

I am trying to create a for loop that will automate adding these values to the URL after 4 minutes.

I have tried to create two lists containing the max values of the two variables and pass them into URLs, but it's not working. The URLs are not returning the data.

```
def parse (self, response):
        l = [1, 2,3,38]
        l2 = [1,2,3,10000]
        for x in l:
           return x
        for p in l2:
            return p
        
        url = f'https://mygames.com/{p}/{x}'
        
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = url,
            callback= self.parse_data,
            headers= self.headers)
```

I have also tried the below code but it isn't working

```
def parse (self , response):
    l = [1, 2,3,38]
    l2 = [1,2,3,10000]
    for x in l:
        for p in l2:
            new_url = f'https://mygames.com/{p}/{x}'
            return new_url
    
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url = new_url,
        callback= self.parse_data,
        headers= self.headers)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the returns doing? Shouldn't the `url` definition and `yield` statement be within the nested loops `for x in l: for p in l2:` to yield all possible combinations?

Comment: Hello @BRemmelzwaal , can you me how to do it via code . I have added a new edit with a nested loop but my output  is still zero.

Comment: Get rid of the `return`, and instead add your entire `yield` statement there.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you will want to get rid of those return statments then you will want to generate a new url for each combination of integers listed, so you should move your yield statement inside the double nested loops.

For example:

```
def parse(self , response):
    l = [1, 2,3,38]
    l2 = [1,2,3,10000]
    for x in l:
        for p in l2:
            new_url = f'https://mygames.com/{p}/{x}'
            yield scrapy.Request(new_url, callback=self.parse_data, headers= self.headers)
```

Although This code looks like it might be more appropriate for the `start_requests` method rather than the `parse` method.

Comment: Thank You , it works . I was wondering though is there a more computational efficient way of doing the above?

Answer (score 0):

I improvised on the time factor, I decided to crawl the website after 70 minutes instead of every 4 minutes , Here is the final code

```
def parse (self , response):
    l = ['1','2','3', '4', '5','6','7','8','9','10', '11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19',            '20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38']
    l2 = ['100' ,'101', '103', '104','105','106','107','108','109','110']
    for x in l:
        for p in l2:
         new_url = f'https://mygames.com/{p}/{x}'
        yield scrapy.Request(url = new_url,callback= self.parse_data,
    headers= self.headers)
```

If I choose 4 minutes ,I would need to keep overwriting the csv files, and   the number of computations per hour would get me blocked by their servers.